# SQL - Lat/Lng Distance Query - Returns nothing if distance = 0

Tags: sql, mysql, database, geocoding

If my input `$latitude` `$longitude` values happen to match exactly the stored values in the DB nothing is returned (eg searching for yourself)...I assume because the distance will be 0.

Im using this query:

```
SELECT *,
(((acos(sin((".$latitude."*pi()/180)) * sin((`lat`*pi()/180))
+cos((".$latitude."*pi()/180)) * cos((`lat`*pi()/180))
* cos(((".$longitude."- `lng`)*pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515)
AS distance
FROM ...

LEFT JOIN ...
ON ...

WHERE 'cat_id' = '$cat_id'

HAVING distance <= $radius
ORDER BY distance ASC
```

One solution I found was to make the input less accurate, by reducing the decimal of the lat lng values - but that's not really a solution.

**How can I alter the query so that the row is still returned if the distance is 0?**

Comment: How could the query be altered so that if the distance is 0 it still returns the row

Comment: Is that the whole query, or just a modified version of it?  I assume there is a `WHERE` condition?

Comment: @Stephen - please see updated above

Comment: you should post the whole thing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `HAVING` clause is killing the output.  Change the query so that its condition is part of the `WHERE`:

```
...
WHERE 'cat_id' = '$cat_id' AND distance <= $radius
```